# WebStorm 10 no debug-console output

Tags: debugging, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm 10 with Chrome and the JetBrains plugin. Debugging worked very well since yesterday.
From one day to the other there is no output in the debug console of WebStorm.

No errors or something else changed...

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Chrome debugging protocol has changed in version 54 (which is stable channel release since October 12). WebStorm debugger is not compatible with these recent changes. The fix is included in WebStorm 2016.3 that is coming soon